# Can we have a glossary of common abbreviations?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to participate more, but I'm finding the sea of acronyms and abbreviations quite difficult to navigate (e.g. [this question](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/57/should-i-call-this-river-overbet-with-an-overpair)).

Can we please have an official glossary of common abbreviations?  (Or can someone link to a definitive reference?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a question and answer that deals with this.

[Is there a comprehensive source for poker terminology?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/142/is-there-a-comprehensive-source-for-poker-terminology/145#145)

I have made my answer community wiki to facilitate keeping it up to date.  New questions on terminology/meanings should be closed as duplicates of this question.

Comment: Should we add this question to the FAQ? I think there should be an easier way to access the question, especially since new users might not know it exists.

Comment: @ARaaen: should should should! Almost asked the same question :(

Answer (score 1):

I agree. Maybe in the form of a Community Wiki question?

Comment: How about just a CW *answer* to a... question? Ask...